# SQL Server 2014 : Convert two comma separated string into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, sql-server-2014

I have two comma-separated string which needs to be converted into a temptable with two columns synchronized based on the index.

If the input string as below

```
a = 'abc,def,ghi'
b = 'aaa,bbb,ccc'
```

then output should be

```
column1 | column2
------------------
abc     | aaa
def     | bbb
ghi     | ccc
```

Let us say I have function `fnConvertCommaSeparatedStringToColumn` which takes in comma-separated string and delimiter as a parameter and returns a column with values. I use this on both strings and get two columns to verify if the count is the same on both sides. But it would be nice two have them in a single temp table. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Let us say I have function which ... returns a column with values.

At that point, the basic idea is to select the column and use the `row_number()` function with both of your strings. Then you can `JOIN` the two together using the `row_number()` result as the matching field for the join.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as a_part, convert(varchar(max), null) as b_part,
             convert(varchar(max), 'abc,def,ghi') + ',' as a,
             convert(varchar(max), 'aaa,bbb,ccc') + ',' as b,
             0 as lev
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(a, charindex(',', a) - 1)),
             convert(varchar(max), left(b, charindex(',', b) - 1)),
             stuff(a, 1, charindex(',', a), ''),
             stuff(b, 1, charindex(',', b), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where a <> '' and lev < 10
     )
select a_part, b_part
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2f7ed97943cd1523012065db60e518e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a bit sneaky you can try.

I don't have your bespoke function so have used the built-in `string_split` function (SQL2016+) - for quickly testing, but assuming the parameters are the same. Ideally, your bespoke function should return its own row number in which case you'd use that instead of a rownumber function.

```
declare @a varchar(20)='abc,def,ghi', @b varchar(20)='aaa,bbb,ccc';
    with v as (
        select a.value A,b.value B, 
          row_number() over(partition by a.value order by (select 1/0))Arn,
          row_number() over(partition by b.value order by (select 1/0))Brn
        from fnConvertCommaSeparatedStringToColumn (@a,',')a
        cross apply fnConvertCommaSeparatedStringToColumn (@b,',')b
    )
    select A,B from v
    where Arn=Brn
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting a (set based) function that can split a string, based on a delimiter, that returns the ordinal position as well. For example [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). Then you can trivially split the value, and `JOIN` on the ordinal position:

```sql
DECLARE @a varchar(100) = 'abc,def,ghi';
DECLARE @b varchar(100) = 'aaa,bbb,ccc';

SELECT A.Item AS A,
       B.Item AS B
FROM dbo.delimitedsplit8k_lead(@a,',') A
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.delimitedsplit8k_lead(@a,',') B ON A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ddf9f6cd927200d6da543b8bc1f2c403)

I use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then if either column has a `NULL` value you know that the 2 delimited lists don't have the same number of delimited values.